# Pushing data to S3 with Apache Flink

Tags: xml, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I have a small test project to push data to an S3 bucket. However, it looks like I am not reading the core-site.xml file in because I am getting the error `java.io.IOException: No file system found with scheme s3a`. How can I properly read in the core-site.xml file and push data to S3?

This is the code:

```
public class S3Sink {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> configs = ConfigUtils.loadConfigs(“path/to/config.yaml");

    final ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromMap(configs);

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().disableSysoutLogging();
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(parameterTool); 

    DataStream<String> messageStream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>(
                    parameterTool.getRequired("kafka.topic"),
                    new SimpleStringSchema(),
                    parameterTool.getProperties()));

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    messageStream.writeAsText("s3a://flink-test/" + id + ".txt").setParallelism(1);

    env.execute();
}
```

This is the configuration change in the flink-conf.yaml file to reference the core-site.xml file:

```
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /path/to/core-site/etc/hadoop/
```

This is my core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>

<!-- Comma separated list of local directories used to buffer
     large results prior to transmitting them to S3. -->
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
</property>

<!-- set your AWS ID using key defined in org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants -->
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>*****</value>
</property>
<!-- set your AWS access key -->
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>*****</value>
</property>
```

Comment: What if you set `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf` to  the folder contianing `core-site.xml`, does it work? also make sure `$HADOOP_HOME` environment variable is properly set.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and set the environment variable HADOOP_HOME to the core-site.xml path. I am running the program locally, so the fs.hdfs.hadoopconf setting doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the core-site.xml file was not being read in is because of the Hadoop's file structure. I had `HADOOP_HOME=path/to/dir/etc/hadoop`. However Hadoop looks for etc/hadoop as part of its file structure to find the core-site.xml. To read the path correctly in the HADOOP_HOME environmental variable, it should be listed just as `HADOOP_HOME=path/to/dir`.

The other issue was why the data wasn't pushing to S3. It is because I was using stream processing. Batch processing works to push data to S3, but stream processing doesn't because of how S3 stores data as a key/value store and new data can't be appended only replaced. For stream processing, Flink keeps appending data to the same file which S3 won't allow so no data gets pushed to S3. So this code works for pushing batches to S3

```
    ExecutionEnvironment ee = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataSet dataSet = ee.readTextFile("/Users/name/Desktop/flinkoutputtest.txt");
    dataSet.writeAsText("s3://flink-test/flink-output/testdoc.txt").setParallelism(1);
    ee.execute();
```